# Is it possible to disable tmux's prefix key?

Tags: terminal, tmux

I use tmux with iTerm's integration facilities, so when using it remotely I only want it for session persistence. I can set the prefix key to something bizarre that I'm unlikely to use but I could imagine some Emacs package suggesting it by default and being puzzled about why it doesn't work.

I would prefer to unset it (I'll use explicit tmux commands if necessary) and hide the status bar. I can hide the bar with `tmux set-option -g status off` but `tmux set-option -g prefix` says `empty value` and `C-b` continues to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Since tmux 2.2](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/39cf9c9d31954198ad73e2b6721a92fe782ee56c) both `prefix` and `prefix2` can be set to `None`. A workaround for earlier versions would still be useful.